# Yocto change psplash image without rebuild the system

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, splash-screen

I'm trying to change yocto splashscreen (generated by psplash) in a current built system, with no yocto rebuild process...
Is there any possibility to change this image?
I think I've to mount the boot partition that contains the start image and replace it...

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yocto psplash recipe can be found [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/psplash/psplash_git.bb).

As you can see, it uses an encoded image `psplash-poky-img.h` generated with help of this [script](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/psplash/tree/make-image-header.sh) then it compiles `/usr/bin/psplash` binary.

If you want to patch your splash screen, you can use make-image-header.sh with your own image, then compile your own psplash binary with yocto SDK help, then replace psplash.

Patching image is dependent to image type.

Nevertheless, easiest way is to create a psplash_git.bbappend file, add your png image in files, and let magic appends:

```
# Example of recipe-core/psplash/psplash_git.bbappend
# (insert my-custom-psplash.png image in recipe-core/psplash/files folder)

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SPLASH_IMAGES = "file://my-custom-psplash.png;outsuffix=default"
```

Comment: Can you please post up some code/scripts to achieve the last point re `bbappend`?

Comment: @RoyShilkrot I edited the answer, is it clear for you?